# Proving/disproving $∀n ∈ \text{positive integers}$, $\left\lceil{\frac{4n^2+1}{n^2}}\right \rceil = 5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is my proof getting anywhere for proving/disproving $∀n ∈ \text{postive integers}$, $$\left\lceil{\frac{4n^2+1}{n^2}}\right \rceil = 5\text{?}$$

$$\left\lceil{\frac{4n^2}{n^2}}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right \rceil = 5$$

$$\left\lceil{\frac{1}{n^2}}\right \rceil = 5 - 4$$

Therefore, for $n \in \mathbb R$, where $n \neq 0$

$$4 < \left\lceil{\frac{4n^2}{n^2}}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right \rceil \le 5$$

$$4 < \left\lceil{4}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right \rceil \le 5$$

$$0 < \left\lceil\frac{1}{n^2}\right \rceil \le 1$$

I feel kind of without purpose once I hit point. Should I be scrapping the inequality and solving for $n$ instead?

Comment: You are starting your "proof" by assuming what it is you're enjoined to prove.

Comment: n=2 results in 5 @mfl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that

$$4=\dfrac{4n^2}{n^2}<\color{red}{\dfrac{4n^2+1}{n^2}}\le\dfrac{4n^2+n^2}{n^2}=\dfrac{5n^2}{n^2}=5.$$ So, we have that

$$\left\lceil  \frac{4n^2+1}{n^2} \right\rceil=5$$ and 
$$\left\lfloor  \frac{4n^2+1}{n^2} \right\rfloor=4.$$

Comment: nitpick:  That should be: $4=\dfrac{4n^2}{n^2}<\color{red}{\dfrac{4n^2+1}{n^2}}\le\dfrac{4n^2+n^2}{n^2}=\dfrac{5n^2}{n^2}=5$ as $n=1$ means $1 = n^2$.

Comment: In my opinion this is the best prove of all of ours.

Comment: @fleablood Sure. You are right. Typo fixed. Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 4):

For all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, we know that $0 < \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1$, hence $\left\lceil \frac{1}{n^2}\right\rceil=1.$

$$\left\lceil  \frac{4n^2+1}{n^2} \right\rceil=\left\lceil 4 +  \frac{1}{n^2} \right\rceil= 4 + \left\lceil  \frac{1}{n^2} \right\rceil=4+1=5$$

Comment: Yeah this just confirms it, thank you for the clear explanation. I had my bounds but didn't know what I was working with!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $5$?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left\lceil  \frac{4n^2+1}{n^2} \right\rceil=5\tag{1}$$
means
$$4 < \frac{4n^2+1}{n^2} \le 5\tag{2}$$
so try to prove (2).  This should be less error prone that transforming expressions with ceilings in them.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is probably okay if you specify all statements are $\iff$ results. That way one *can* reverse direction.  Otherwise you are assuming what you need to prove.

$[\frac {4n^2 + 1}{n^2}] = 5 \iff$

$[4 + \frac 1{n^2}] = 5 \iff$

$[\frac 1{n^2}] = 5 - 4$  (actually do you know if that is true?  I don't feel comfortable with that step.  I'd suggest you first prove that if $k\in \mathbb Z$ then $[k + y] = k + [y]$.  [$*$].)

$\iff 0< \frac 1{n^2} \le 1$.

And then continue.

$\iff  1 \le n^2$ which as $n$ is a non-zero integer is true.

And we would be done.

But this is a *backwards* proof and *only* works because every step was $\iff$. If *any* one step was not reversible, the proof would *fail*[$**$]. To do a direct proof, we take a new sheet of paper and work forward.

$n\ne 0; n\in \mathbb Z \implies$

$n^2 > 0; n^2\ne 0; n^2 \in \mathbb Z \implies$

$n^2 \ge 1 \implies$

$0 < \frac 1{n^2} \le 1 \implies$

$[\frac 1{n^2}] = 1 \implies$

$[4 + \frac 1{n^2}] = 4 + 1 \implies$ [$*$]

$[\frac {4n^2 + 1}{n^2}] = 5$.

======

[$*$]

Let $[k + y] = m$ were $k \in \mathbb Z$.

then $m - 1 < k +y \le m$

so $(m-k) -1 < y \le (m-k)$

so $[y] = m-k = [k+y] - k$.

====

P.S.

As GEdgar points out a more elegant proof would be

$[\frac {4n^2 +1}{n^2}] = 5 \iff$

$4 < \frac {4n^2 + 1}{n^2} \le 5 \iff$

$4n^2 < 4n^2 + 1 \le 5n^2 \iff$

$0 <  1 \le n^2$ which is true.

To make this a forward proof:

$n \ne 0 \implies n^2 \ge 1$ so

$0< 1  \le n^2$

$4n^2 < 4n^2 + 1 \le 5n^2$

$4 < \frac{4n^2 + 1}{n^2} \le 5$

$[\frac {4n^2 + 1}{n^2} ] = 5$.

[$**$]

A proof that $1 = 5$:

$1 = 5 \implies$

$1 -3 = 5-3 \implies$

$-2 = 2\implies$

$(-2)^2 = 2^2\implies$

$4 =4 $ which is true.

So $1 = 5$.  Notice *every* step of the proof is valid *except* the conclusion.

$-2 = 2 \implies (-2)^2 = 2^2$ but

$-2 = 2 \not \Leftarrow (-2)^2 = 2^2$.

A Conclusion $\to $ true statement is only valid if we do: conclusion $\Leftarrow ... \Leftarrow$ true statement.

But conclusion $\implies ... \implies$ true statement, is *NEVER* valid.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The ceiling of a real number is always an integer. So $0<\lceil x \rceil\leq 1$ is equivalent to $\lceil x\rceil = 1$, or $0<x\leq 1$.